# regular expression for pick the work from the group

Tags: php, regex

How to pick the work using RegEx

```
|=|3|=|5|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf
```

i want to pick **yes**  from the

```
|=|3|=|5|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf
```

Can u tell me the preg match  regular expression for the above collection ?

Comment: Are you processing some kind of CSV data?

Comment: More detail needed... Do you want the position of the "Yes", or the value is the fifth block, or just whether or not there is a Yes or what?

Comment: To elaborate on KennyTM's response... you'll probably need to give us more info about what you actually need to do (context, various cases, etc) if you want a useful response.

Comment: maximum it is before of the last ,

that is |=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf

Comment: In your post title, did you say "work" but mean "word?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
$tokens = explode('|', '|=|3|=|5|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf');
echo $tokens[10];
```

See: http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php

**EDIT**

> *Bharanikumar:*
>
> maximum it is before of the last , that is |=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf

Okay, I believe you mean that you're looking for the token before the last token. If so, try:

```
$tokens = explode('|=|', '|=|3|=|5|=|5|=|3|=|Yes|=|gdfsgsdf');
echo $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-2];
```

Note that this assumes you have at least 2 tokens in your string.

And as PP pointed out, `|=|` is probably your delimiter.

Comment: The token here appears to be '|=|'